# Why does the 1/2 coefficient in the geodesic equation cancel the 2 in the $\partial_{r}g_{tt}$ term but not the 2 in the $g^{rr}$ term?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, geodesics

In the Newtonian limit, the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^{r}_{tt}=-\tfrac{1}{2}g^{rr} \partial_{r}g_{tt}$ in the geodesic equation reduces to $$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r}-1\right)\frac{2GM}{c^2r^2} c^2$$ which further reduces to $$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r}-1\right)\frac{GM}{c^2r^2} c^2.$$

My question is. Why does the $\frac{1}{2}$ coefficient cancel the $2$ in the $\partial_{r}g_{tt}$ term $\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r^2}\right)$  but not the $2$ in the $g^{rr}$ term $\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r}-1\right)$ or $\left(\frac{rs}{r}-1\right)$?

In other words, why doesn't the Newtonian limit for the geodesic equation reduce to $$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -\left(\frac{GM}{c^2r}-1\right) \frac{2GM}{c^2r^2} c^2$$

EDIT: there is no need to distribute to cancel the 2 inside the parentheses as the parentheses were placed there by me to make it easier to differentiate between the $g^{rr}$ and the $\partial_{r}g_{tt}$ terms within the Christoffel symbol.

Comment: Because the second thing you wrote just doesn't make sense. $1/2 * (1-G2) \neq (1-G)$, which should be obvious

Comment: the 1 in $\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)$ is a constant so you can simply remove it leaving $\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)$

Comment: You can't remove the 1 for being a constant. But also, these are factors, not terms. They are multiplied together, so you don't distribute the $1/2$. This is an algebra question, though, not physics.

Comment: I rewrote the question, reflecting the correct order of the factors in the Christoffel symbol, therefore should the 1/2 cancel the 2 in the $g^{rr}$ term $\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r}-1\right)$ and not the 2 in the $\partial_{r}g_{tt}$ term $\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r^2}\right)$? If not, why?

Comment: @AnthonySmith the order of multiplication here has zero importance as to how you move and cancel factors, but you'd absolutely need to distribute to cancel the 2 inside the parentheses, that's just a fact you'll have to deal with.

Comment: @Triatticus, thanks but parenthesis were placed thereby me to make it easier to read, they don't actually exist in the equation. What I'm just trying to ascertain if there some hidden rule as to why one 2 can be cancelled over the other.

Comment: If the parentheses were not there then it's likely an error on part of the author or something else since there is then an ambiguity in what is grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

As you say in the question the Christoffel symbol is:

$$ \Gamma^r{}_{tt} = \frac{GM}{c^2r^2}\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right) $$

so we get:

$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -\frac{GM}{c^2r^2}\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right) U^tU^t$$

The Newtonian limit has $U^t \approx c$, and $2GM/c^2r \ll 1$ so that:

$$ \left(1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right) \approx 1 $$

Making these substitutions gives us the expected result:

$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} \approx -\frac{GM}{r^2} $$

You do not want or need the $\tfrac12$ to cancel anything in the term $\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)$ because that term goes to one in the Newtonian limit.

Comment: I see. However, if the $g^{rr}$ term was written in the convention $\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r}-1\right)$ then wouldn't the $\tfrac12$ cancel the $2$ leaving behind $\left(\frac{GM}{c^2r}-1\right)$? Full disclosure, I'm writing a paper and believe that the geodesic equation can be solved in such a way that it takes on the following form $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = \partial_{r}g_{tt}  u^t u^t $ indicating that, relative to an external observer, acceleration in the radial direction coincides with the speed of light reducing wrt the radial distance from a massive object, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: @AnthonySmith Obviously not because $\tfrac12 \left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r}-1\right)
 = \left(\frac{GM}{c^2r}-\tfrac12\right)$