# In the Schwarzschild metric how is the inverse for the $g_{rr}$ component written?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In the Schwarzschild metric how is the inverse written for the component $g_{rr}$, which is $\frac{1}{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$?

Does $g^{rr}$ =$\left(\frac{2GM}{rc^2}-1\right)$, and therefore, $\left(\frac{rs}{r}-1\right)$, or is it written as $1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}$

Comment: $g_{rr} = (1- r_s/r)^{-1}$ and $g^{rr} = 1 - r_s/r$

Comment: @JohnRennie, thank you sir. Then for the $g^{rr}$ component in the geodesic equation why is this form used $\left(\frac{rs}{r}-1\right)$?

Comment: The metric can be written either with a +--- or a -+++ signature. Both work fine along as you are consistent. Presumably your book uses +---. I used -+++ above because that's what I'm used to.

Comment: @JohnRennie, Ah I see, thank you. One last thing, If you have the time, could you take a look at the this and provide and answer? I would really appreciate it- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/774408/why-does-the-1-2-coefficient-in-the-geodesic-equation-cancel-the-2-in-the-part

Answer (score 1):

For the record, if we use the -+++ signature (beloved of general relativists) the Schwarzschild metric and its inverse is:

$$ g_{\mu\nu} = \left( \begin{matrix}
-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ g^{\mu\nu} = \left( \begin{matrix}
-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1-\frac{r_s}{r} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{r^2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta} \end{matrix} \right) $$